# yaml configuration for add one more script file to google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

I am making a php app using googel app engine. In that, i want to provide a link to another php file in a different directory. but i dont know the yaml configuration for doing so. the yaml file i am using is like this:

```
application: tryappbhargav
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php

- url: /signin/
  script: index.php

- url: /signin/index.*
  script: index.php
```

i am not able to go to the file 'index.php' inside the directory 'signin'. Please help!! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is you problem.

```
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

It will match everything starting with a '/', so nothing gets past this match.   Have a read of the docs, you need to place more specific matches before more general url patterns.

Comment: thank you for the concern.... but i am already getting the file 'index.php' file with the handler '-url:/.*' part. my problem is i have a link in the 'index.php' for a file inside another folder called '/signin/'. when i click on that link, i am not going to that file. instead, only the url in the address bar in changing, but the page that is loading is the previous itself. i hope i am explaining it correctly. are you getting what my problem is? the handler i am using is '-url: /signin/'

Comment: My answer stands.  Every URL that is presented will be intercepted by /.* handler.  The fact you have the same index.php for each of your regexes is a seperate issue.